# Second level domain and load balancer

Tags: apache, load-balancing, virtualhost

I need to implement load-balancing for the root and for second-level domain of the website. Technically basic configuration needs to be:

```
Balancing for mysite.com
mysite.com -> 127.0.0.1:8101
mysite.com -> 127.0.0.1:8102
Balancing for account.mysite.com
account.mysite.com -> 127.0.0.1:8201
account.mysite.com -> 127.0.0.1:8202
```

I'm not familiar in Apache configuring so I only know how to set up a virtual host for account.mysite.com and also I got some balancing samples for a root but I don't understand how to combine both of this. Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at [mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) and use something like this in your `<VirtualHost>`.

```
<Proxy balancer://mysiteCluster>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8102
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8102
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / balancer://mysiteCluster/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mysiteCluster/
```

Do a similar configuration for `account.mysite.com`. Remember that you might have to add some stuff for session stickiness depending on application, it's all in the link above though.

Comment: Is it correct to use Proxy directive in VirtualHost one? As far as I understand Proxy directive already does what I need for root path. The concern I have at the moment is do I still need VirtualHost for account.mysite.com and how it works with Proxy.

Comment: If you put the proxy stuff in your `VirtualHost` you will make sure it operate on the correct site, and also that `/` represent the correct `DocumentRoot`. It ofc depend on your setup what you want to do.

Comment: Works fine for me but with little correction: ProxyPass / balancer://mysiteCluster/ (trailing slash at the end) Same for reverse.

Comment: Oh, I will edit my answer.